# Python network - node labeling / graph visualization

Tags: python, pandas, network-programming, visualization, graph-visualization

I am new to Python and trying to visualize a medium size network (nodes=2252 | edges=36075) with `networkx`. Currently, I have two simple problems which I could not solve, despite some hours of research:

1. After importing and rearranging the data (the code for it can be seen on the bottom of this feed), I draw the graph with the following code:

   ```
   G=nx.DiGraph()
   G.add_nodes_from(newnds)
   G.add_weighted_edges_from(newedgs)
   nx.draw(G,node_size=10)
   ```

   Here, the problem occurs that the labels I defined are viewed as additional nodes, overlaying the actual nodes. So the question would be: Did I made a mistake in the specification or the code?
2. If I try to circumvent this problem by letting `nx` draw the nodes on the fly with

   ```
   G=nx.DiGraph()
   G.add_weighted_edges_from(newedgs)
   nx.draw(G,node_size=10)
   ```

   the network is visualized but gives the impression that all nodes are connected to each other in some way, which is not the case as it is a directed graph. The result:[image] 
   Thus is there an option in `networkx` to spread the network similar to the layout function `Force Atlas 2` in Gephi?

The code to import and rearang the data is as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
nodesdata = 'XXX/Documents/nodes.csv'
nodes = pd.read_csv(nodesdata)
nodes.head()
import pandas as pd
edgesdata = 'XXX/Documents/edges.csv'
edges = pd.read_csv(edgesdata)
edges.head()
nds=nodes[['Id','Label']]
edgs=edges[['Source','Target','Weight']]
df_edges_t1=edges["Source"].tolist()
df_edges_t2=edges["Target"].tolist()
df_edges_t3=edges["Weight"].tolist()
newedgs=list(zip(df_edges_t1,df_edges_t2,df_edges_t3))
print(newedgs)
df_nodes_t1=nodes["Id"].tolist()
df_nodes_t2=nodes["Label"].tolist()
newnds=list(zip(df_nodes_t1,df_nodes_t2))
print(newnds)
```